# How do i create .txt file with PHP code in VScode

Tags: php

I have just started to learn PHP, and started it with VS Code
But unfortunately when trying to create a new simple 'data.txt' file, but without any luck. here is the code

```php
<?php
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';
$pageTitle = 'Форма';
include 'header.php';
$groups = [1 => 'Приятели', 2 => 'Бивши', 3 => 'Бъдещи', 4 => 'Колеги'];
$error = true;

if ($_POST) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $selectedGroup = (int) $_POST['group'];

    if (mb_strlen($username) < 4) {
        echo '<p>Името е прекалено късо</p>';
        $error = true;
    }
    if (mb_strlen($phone) < 6 || mb_strlen($phone) > 12) {
        echo '<p>Невалиден Телефон</p>';
        $error = true;
    }
    if (!array_key_exists($selectedGroup, $groups)) {
        echo '<p>Невалидна Група</p>';
        $error = true;
    }

    if (!$error) {
        $result = $username . '!' . $phone . '!' . $selectedGroup;
        file_put_contents('data.txt', $result);
    }
}
?> 

<a href="index.php">Списък</a>
<form method="POST">
    <div> Име: <input type="text" name="username" /> </div>
    <div>Телефон <input type="text" name="phone" /> </div>
    <div> 
        <select name="group">
            <?php foreach ($groups as $key => $values) {
                echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $values . '</options>';
            } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="Добави" /> </div>
</form>
<?php include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Every time i reload the server it does not create any new '.txt' file, even when i try with different values i am not able to create.`enter code her`enter code here`e`
I looked up to find different information, i have tried to change the permissions to -- 755 -- 'Path' ==>> /var/www/html.
The same goes to debugging, i have tried but no errors are displaying, assuming it is some small thing i tried to look into the code 100 times but with no result.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

There's no condition where `$error` could be false (you initialize it to true and only set it to true), so you can never enter the `if(!$error){` block.

You'll probably want to change that initial

```
$error = true;
```

to

```
$error = false;
```